# How to invoke an event after losing focus from a textbox that was just filled out?

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two text boxes: A and B using `Html.textboxfor`. TextBox 'A' is enabled and TextBox 'B' is disabled.

When I type values in Textbox 'A' and change focus away from the textbox, TextBox 'B' should be populated with some value.

For example: I am entering the value of TextBox A = "King"; if the focus is lost from the box, the value in the Textbox B should be "Peter", which should be filled automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure about ASP, but the event you should be listening to is `blur`

Comment: It seems can be solved by jquery onblur(), however would there be any logic you want to apply between the textbox A and content displays on textbox B? if it correlated with data query, you may need to use ajax call in side your jquery blur event as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can jsut give the textbox an attrbiute of onblur and call a method which will fill the second textbox

something like:

```
   <script language="javascript">
       function fllB()
       {
          var txtB = document.getElementById("txtB");
          var txtA = document.getElementById("txtA");

          if (txtA.value == "King")
          {
              txtB.value = "Peter";
          }
        }
    </script>

<input type="text" id="txtA" onblur="fillB()" />
<input type="text" id="txtB" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the javascript function that I wrote to validate my input "Price" currency value.

```
<script language="javascript">
function validatePrice(textBoxId) {
    var textVal = textBoxId.value;
    var regex = /^(\$|)([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$/;
    var passed = textVal.match(regex);
    if (passed == null) {
        alert("Enter price only. For example: 523.36 or $523.36");
        textBoxId.Value = "";
    }
}
```

If you want to fire the validation after you lost a focus from text box, then use “onblur” event which is as same as OnLostFocus() in most of the WinForm controls.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox19" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="183px" 
                onblur="javascript:return validatePrice(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ASP.NET, why dont you used the .NET toolbox like asp:textbox. It will be easier to maintain also.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text == "King")
    {
        TextBox2.Text = "Peter";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want your second textbox to always be disabled? If so include the disabled property in the textboxfor:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor( x => x.XXX, new { id = "txtA" }) %>    
<%: Html.TextBoxFor( x => x.XXX, new { id = "txtB", disabled="true" }) %>
```

For the JavaScript, I'm assuming you are using the jquery that is included with mvc: (If you don't want to clear txtb if the value is removed from box A, then remove the else statement)

```
    $(function() 
{
    $("#txtA").change(function()
    {
        if ($("#txtA").val().length > 0) {

            $("#txtB").val(function()
            {
                // Do something to populate #txtb ex: Peter
                var myVar = "Peter";

                return myVar;
            }); 
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#txtB").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function()
  {

    $("#txtA").change(function()
    {
      if(this.value == "King") 
        $("#txtB").attr("disabled", "").val( "Peter" );
    });

  });
</script>
```